# Why is my hostname set to a random number (228) in the bash prompt on OS X?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

Today I saw that when I open a terminal, the bash prompt displays `username@228~:`. When I type in `pwd` I get `/Users/username` so I was wondering where does this 228 come from? It wasn't like that couple of days ago and I am not sure what introduced this change.

My OS is `OS X Yosemite 10.10.5`.

In `.bash_profile` I have `export PS1="\u@\h\w: "`.

Comment: What happens if you use the full hostname `\H` , i.e. `export PS1="\u@\H\w: "`? And what's the output of `hostname`?

Comment: Okay, I think it is clear now. `hostname` outputs the full hostname of the network I am currently connected to. It also happens to begin with the number `228`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the list of prompt strings (see PROMPTING in `man bash`):

```
\h     the hostname up to the first `.'
```

Usually, this gives a nice short hostname but in your case leads to the slightly confusing `228`.

Answer (score -1):

You are connected to the wrong Internet provider.
Yep, in your WiFi router, you have (at least) TWO WiFi networks.
You are connected to the one which is accessible to everybody.
Probably, your ISP allows you to connect country-wide with the same credentials you use at your home.

This is the explanation, but the solution ... doesn't exist.